# I've selected to auto install updates but I am still seeing updates available

Tags: updates

Noob here. System is a Lenovo ThinkPad 11e with N2940 Celeron processor (quad-core @ 1.83GHz) and 8GB RAM. This is my first time installing Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) and working with Linux in general. [Pictures 3 and 4 are the updating options I have selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Q1p.jpg) However, when I open the Ubuntu Software application, I am seeing an available update (picture 2)

I am also seeing another available update (picture 1) under the additional drivers tab, yet I'm still a little unsure about it. Again, this is my first time working with Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. My question is why are there available updates to install if I have selected those options in pictures 3 and 4? Should I install all of these? Are the updates in picture 1 and picture 2 related at all, or are they two completely different things?

Also, In another thread I read to run the commands: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade. Would this be the same as installing these updates or is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

**Updates come from different sources**. By default, only the '-security' source is selected for unattended upgrades. Only packages from that source will be automatically upgraded.

Non-security upgrades come from **other sources** (like '-upgrades') and **won't be upgraded** automatically in a default install of Ubuntu.

Users of current Ubuntu Desktop and Server systems can **change the sources** used by unattended upgrades: Configure the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades in a text editor (vim, nano, *not* a word processor). Use sudo to launch the text editor. At the top of the file, you will see the entries for other sources.

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Simply uncomment (remove the '//') from lines you wish to enable, or add other repositories if you wish. The file must be edited by root. Enabling '-proposed' is strongly discouraged.

Users of desktop Snaps instead of .deb packages won't get updates through unattended-upgrades nor through Software Updater. Those come through the 'snap refresh' command. An unattended upgrade mechanism for them has not yet been created.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not stated any dedicated purpose of using ubuntu so I am considering that you are using it for general purpose.

The ubuntu updates are basically updates for all the utilities and system softwares which are installed on your computer. Ubuntu software updater basically show the updates for the softwares which are installed on your system and fall under this sources list: `/etc/apt/sources.list` *(You don't need to worry about much details until you get used to)*

So if you are ok with little bit more internet usage then you can go ahead installing all the updates. But if you wish to save your data usage then go for security updates and driver updates, common softwares like editor and media players you can skip.

I hope this makes clear about ubuntu udpates. Please let me know if you have still doubt, or i missundertsood your question.

For detailed informations you can go through: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates

Cheers !